# Where is appDelegate?

Tags: xcode, cocoa, appdelegate

I'm new to XCode/Obj-C, so this might be a bad question:

I created a new Cocoa Application in XCode, and want to change something in my appDelegate file. The problem is, I don't have an appDelegate file. Am I supposed to make one? (How)? Or is XCode supposed to make one for me by default? (Why isn't it?)

Comment: Are you sure it's not there?  Check if the folders are minimized.

Comment: I'm sure. I created a document based application, so that might be why there's nothing created by default, but then how do I create a delegate? I've seen plenty of document based applications with app delegates.

Comment: Oh I see.  In that case, then just create a new class named app delegate, then create a new object in your MainMenu.xib with the class you just created.

Comment: Hi Mirror, I can't replicate your problem. If you create a project you should automatically get an AppDelegate. Even when you are creating a document based application. Perhaps when your location settings are not default, xcode puts the AppDelegate in a different folder, but in all cases when building an OSX cocoa application xcode should create an Appdelegate for you. I would recommend creating a new cocoa application and not try to tweak in an AppDelegate. This is the delegate of your NSApplication singleton.